# T4 Template and Server.MapPath

Tags: t4

I am trying to get the folder names inside the Views folder using T4 Template and it keeps giving me the following errors:

Error   3   Compiling transformation: The name 'Server' does not exist in the current context   c:\Projects\LearningASPMVC\LearningASPMVCSolution\LearningMVC\StronglyTypedViews.tt 20  47
Error   4   A namespace does not directly contain members such as fields or methods C:\Projects\LearningASPMVC\LearningASPMVCSolution\LearningMVC\StronglyTypedViews.cs 1   1   LearningMVC

Here is the T4 Template:

```
<#@ template language="C#" debug="True" hostspecific="True" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>

<#@ assembly name="System.Web" #>

<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Web" #>


using System; 



namespace StronglyTypedViews 
{

    <# 

     string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(Server.MapPath("Views")); 

     foreach(string folderName in folders) 
     {

     #>  

     public static class <#= folderName #> { } 


     <# } #>        

}
```

UPDATE: Got it working using the physical path:

```
<#@ template language="C#" debug="True" hostspecific="True" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>

<#@ assembly name="System.Web" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Web.Mvc" #>


<#@ import namespace="System.Web.Mvc" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Web" #>


using System; 

namespace StronglyTypedViews 
{

    <# 

     string viewsFolderPath = @"C:\Projects\LearningASPMVC\LearningASPMVCSolution\LearningMVC\"; 

     string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(viewsFolderPath + "Views");


     foreach(string folderName in folders) 
     {

     #> 

     public static class <#= System.IO.Path.GetFileName(folderName) #> {         
     <#      
      foreach(string file in Directory.GetFiles(folderName))      {
         #>          
         public const string <#= System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file) #> = "<#= System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file).ToString()  #>";

     <# } #>



     <#  } #>

     }




}
```

Comment: The problem is that HttpContext.Current is null!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

T4 templates are executed in a temporary context that visual studio creates, and is well outside your web application. That temporary context is intended for generating the output text file. It is not a web application in any way, and is unrelated to the web application your are authoring. As a result, *System.Web.HttpContext* doesn't have any value assigned, and *MapPath()* cannot be invoked.

*Environment.CurrentDirectory* isn't much help either, as the template is executed in some temporary folder.

What can you do? If you can use absolute paths, go ahead and do that. Otherwise, adding the *hostspecific* attribute in the *<#@ template#>* directive will allow you to the *Host* variable, and its [ResolvePath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.texttemplating.itexttemplatingenginehost.resolvepath.aspx) method. *ResolvePath*  lets you resolve paths relative to the TT file itself.

For example (example.tt):

```
<#@ template language="C#" hostspecific="True" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
// <#=Host.ResolvePath(".")#>
```

Output (example.cs):

```
// C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\MvcApplication1\MvcApplication1\.
```

[Oleg Sych's post about the template directive](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/02/t4-template-directive/) has a section about the hostspecific attribute.